# PDFRenderer.jar version

Tags: java, jar, pdf-generation, version, pdfrenderer

I have a project which uses PDFRenderer.jar v1.0.5 which was probably downloaded from http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs/pdf-renderer/1.0.5

A quick google search finds the PDFRenderer.jar in a project at https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/downloads which shows v0.9.1 as the latest version

```
version | last-modified | Ant version | # of objects in com.sun.pdfview
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1.0.5  | 2009-03-15    | 1.7.1       | 82 
 0.9.1  | 2011-09-15    | 1.8.2       | 91
```

The problem is that the 0.9.1 version has a more recent last-modified date, and has more objects in the `com.sun.pdfview` package than the 1.0.5 version.

Does anyone know which one is the most recent version?

Answer (score 0):

don't go through version number because jar provider are different, go through last-modified date.